# Replace function in SQLITE

Tags: android, sqlite

I was trying to duplicate this SQLite statement from the line of code below:

```
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("update tbl_details SET ticket = replace(ticket, " + tempID + ", " + ticket + ")", null);
```

to this one:

```
SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put("ticket", "replace(ticket, " + tempID + ", " + ticket + ")");
        db.update("tbl_details", cv, null, null);
        return true;
```

What I am trying to do is to get a New ID and replace all instances of the old temporary ID in the database. But the code above is changing all the records in ticket column.

Please help. Thank you!

Comment: Well:  [`update(...)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#update%28java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[]%29):  *whereClause  the optional WHERE clause to apply when updating. Passing null will update all rows*. You pass `null`, hence all rows are affected.

Comment: What should I put in the ContentValues cv?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `ContentValues` to bind literal values only, not expressions like `replace(...)`.

To run the raw `UPDATE` SQL, just use `execSQL()` instead of `rawQuery()`. `rawQuery()` alone won't actually run the code until the returned `Cursor` is moved.